# Xamarin Forms - пара вопросов про лицензию

Tags: c#, лицензирование, xamarin

1. У производителя Xamarin Forms нет представительства в России, поэтому накладную подписать некому, а по другому у нас в фирме не делается. Есть ли возможность все же как-то легально приобрести Xamarin Forms нашей фирмой? (за исключением оплаты своей частной картой)
2. В новой бесплатной версии Visual Studio 2015 Community включен Xamarin. Но не понятно, обозначает ли это, что использование этой технологии стало бесплатным? (звучит маловероятным)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Visual Studio 2015 Community включен [Xamarin Starter Edition](https://xamarin.com/starter).

> Starter Edition is our free tier, which allows anyone to get a taste of mobile development in C# by writing small app[*](https://xamarin.com/starter#fn) which can be deployed to devices and published to app stores.

По сноске есть определение small app:

> Apps must meet size restrictions(128k of compiled C# or F# code), include only managed code (not Objective-C/Swift, Java, or C/C++ libraries), and use Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android, **not Xamarin.Forms**.

**UPD:** http://www.syssoft.ru/Xamarin/ - официальный партнер-реселлер в России. Работают с юрлицами. Принимают оплату по безналу.